# How to get redirected URL without downloading file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm writing a web scraper and basically what I'm working with using requests and bs4 is a site that provides all content in the style https://downlaod.domain.com/xid_39428423_1 which then redirects you to the actual file. What I want is a command which fetches the redirect link before downloading the file, so I can check if I've already downloaded said file. The current code snippet I have is this:

```
def download_file(file_url,s,thepath):
    if not os.path.isdir(thepath):
        os.makedirs(thepath)
    print 'getting header'
    i = s.head(file_url)
    urlpath = i.url
    name = urlsplit(urlpath)[2].split('/')
    name = name[len(name)-1]
    if not os.path.exists(thepath + name):
        print urlpath
        i = s.get(urlpath)
        if i.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            with iopen(thepath + name, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(i.content)
        else:
            return False
```

If I change the s.head to s.get it works, but it downloads the file twice. Is there any way to get the redirected url without downloading?

**SOLVED**
The final code looks like this, thanks!

```
def download_file(file_url,s,thepath):
    if not os.path.isdir(thepath):
        os.makedirs(thepath)
    print 'getting header'
    i = s.get(file_url, allow_redirects=False)
    if i.status_code == 302:
        urlpath = i.headers['location']
    else: 
        urlpath = file_url
    name = urlsplit(urlpath)[2].split('/')
    name = name[len(name)-1]
    if not os.path.exists(thepath + name):
        print urlpath
        i = s.get(urlpath)
        if i.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            with iopen(thepath + name, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(i.content)
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `allow_redirects` flag and set it to `False` (see [the documentation](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)). That way the `.get()` will not follow the redirect, which allows you to inspect the response before retrieving the file itself.

In other words, instead of this:

```
i = s.head(file_url)
urlpath = i.url
```

You could write:

```
i = s.get(file_url, allow_redirects=False)
urlpath = i.headers['location']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked perfectly!
I also added in an if statement to check the status code just incase the link wasn't a redirect.

Comment: In python3 the following works: 

`i = requests.head(file_url)
urlpath = info.headers['location']`